# Magento Error SQLSTATE

Tags: mysql, magento, php

Magento is giving me a lot of trouble every time I stop the server/mymac and restart it. Does anyone have the same problem? How did you fix it? The error message that it gave me is

Log record number 913324899 (but it changes when refresh the page) 
SQLSTATE [42000]: Syntax error or access violation 1286 Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'

Comment: obviously, you need to enable `innodb` engine, therefore voting as belonging to serverfault ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Did you check your innodb engine is enable or not?

please check it out